# Python Continue loop after negative input has been entered

Tags: python-3.x

I'm slowly learning python but I can't seem to get past this problem:

```
while True:
        try:
               numCats = int(input())

        except ValueError or numCats < 0:
                print('Please enter a valid number.')
                continue

        else:
            break
```

I think I'm missing something obvious here. I want the loop to continue if the user enters a ValueError or a negative number.

Comment: remove `else` statement. Also `continue` is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two conditions:

```
while True:
    # exception handling
    try:
      numCats = int(input())
    except ValueError:
      print('Please enter a valid number.')
      continue

    # the input was indeed an integer
    if numCats < 0:
      print('Please enter a valid number.')
      continue

    print('All checks passed!')
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
valid = False
while True:
    try:
        numCats = int(input())
        if numCats >= 0:
            valid = True
        elif numCats < 0:
            print('Please enter a valid number.')
    except ValueError:
        valid = False
        print('Please enter a valid number.')
    if valid:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
           numCats = int(input())
           if  numCats < 0:
                  print('Please enter a valid number.')
                  continue
    except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid number.')
            continue

    else:
        break
```